# Stack builder Postgres on GNU/Linux

Tags: postgresql, fedora

I am trying to run Stack builder Plus for Postgres on Fedora and I am getting su authentication error after inserting the correct password.[image]
this what I get when I try to open stack builder Postgres

I have installed Stack builder as part  Postgres Server

Comment: Are you sure you are providing correct password? Remember that (depending on configuration) `sudo`usually asks for the password of the non privileged used that is calling it. Of course, message on your screenshot is asking for root password. But I would suggest to not blindly trust in it (maybe is sudo instead of su what is being using to autenticate). On the other hand, if it is sudo you also need to check that your user is in the sudoers file or belongs to a group that it is in it (typically 'sudo': `# adduser myUser sudo`).

Comment: yes I am sure I have supplied the correct password and I have installed Postgres on another computer still I get the same error when I try to open Stack builder

Comment: Which password did you provided? Root password, your own or tryed both? Did you tryed sudo AND su with other commands (such as ls) in command line?  BTW, whatever could be the cause, if sudo or su works correctly (and you provide propper password) you can overcome it by manually performing sudo so the application you are trying to run won't need to perform su/sudo by itself or, if it still does, sudo/su will not ask any password at all because you already are root.

What happen if you try `su ls /` and `sudo ls /`?

Comment: when I click stackbuilder under the applications menu in Fedora Linux it prompts for  root password and I have tried root's password , my own password, postgres enterprisedb user's password but nothing works

Comment: Then try to open a terminal and type the commands I suggested to you. We haven't any glass ball to see what is happening without information. You also can try to install some graphical sudo (or su) wrapper which is wat the message in the screenshot you provided is claiming for…

Comment: I get thisn  when I run sudo ls /: bin     dev    home   lib64    media   opt    root    sbin   sys    usr    booy   etc   lib    lost+found   mnt   proc   run   srv   tmp   var

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179892/discussion-between-samuel-m-kabiena-and-bitifet).